# what is wrong in my code getting current page path?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have my visualstudio vcproj file at c:\vsproj\example\test\test.vcproj

under this path i have some other files like e test.cpp file and also a dll test.dll is there.

so totally under tha path c:\vsproj\example\test i have

1) test.vsproj 2) test.dll 3) test.cpp

normally to get the cuurent folder path we use ".\" so i have applied the technique to get

the dll path which is reside where the test.cpp   file is there

now in test.cpp some where else i have written

**string str= ".\\test.dll"** to get the test.dll path. But i am not getting the dll path into the

my idea is i have to get the path in the variable str="c:\vsproj\example\test\test.dll"

but i am getting ".\test.dll" wat is wrong can u correct me??
variable str; how to get the dll path that in this scenario...

Comment: Can you try and elaborate further? I can't quite figure out what you mean by "not getting the dll path into the variable str".

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this: str = " c:\vsproj\example\test\test.dll" ?

Comment: Yes exactly this is myintension

Answer (score 1):

> string str= ".\test.dll" to get the
>   test.dll path. But i am not getting
>   the dll path into the
>
> my idea is i have to get the path in
>   the variable
>   str="c:\vsproj\example\test\test.dll"
>
> but i am getting ".\test.dll" wat is
>   wrong can u correct me?? variable str;
>   how to get the dll path that in this
>   scenario...

It's doing exactly what you're asking it to do. What you appear to *want* it to do isn't going to be achieved this way.

You'll need to get the current working directory and prepend it to "\test.dll", rather than just specifying "\test.dll".

Comment: In .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx. Otherwise, look up GetModuleFileName or even _getcwd.

Answer (score 0):

check with Filemon program. it shows you where the code is trying to search and show you where you do wrong..

Answer (score 0):

String has nothing to do with paths. How could it understand what you want? It is just a mere collection of letters.

As others suggested, try using _getcwd and appending "\test.dll" at the end of it.

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is [`GetFullPathName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963.aspx).  It works on C strings, not C++ strings though. Have a look at the examples in the linked article. 
(You can safely ignore the panicky bits about multi-threaded applications. The same problem actually exists for single-threaded app too. If the current directory changes, `..\xyz\` changes too.)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **[_getcwd(char* buf, int len)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf98bd4y%28VS.80%29.aspx)** to get the current working directory: